# How to set reminder one year ahead using EventKit Framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, eventkit

Im trying to set the start date 1 year in advance when adding an event using Eventkit Framework.

so far I have looked on SO, done a google search and tried

```
controller.event.startDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval: 525960];
controller.event.endDate= [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

I get an error saying `NSDate declares the selector initWithTimeInterval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not do it as interval= 525960.

Instead use NSCalender and then manipulate by adding 1 to current year.

```
NSCalendar *calendar=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] ;
components.year=1;
NSDate *newDate=[calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate:[NSDate date] options: 0];
NSLog(@"Next year : %@", newDate);
```

Comment: You should have asked why not to use 525960?  Because this interval is not constant for each other, leap year, leap seconds etc.